# Test on SauceLabs open www page and than close connection

Tags: c#, internet-explorer, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, saucelabs

I wrote a test in c# to run on IE 11 - Windows 8.1.

After open BaseUrl nothing will happen. And after few seconds I have a message: "ERROR user closed connection while waiting for command to complete".

I define an IE browser like this:

```
DesiredCapabilities capabillities = DesiredCapabilities.InternetExplorer();
capabillities.SetCapability(CapabilityType.Platform, "Windows 8.1");
capabillities.SetCapability(CapabilityType.Version, "11");
```

Code from which I start test:

```
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(baseURL); 

driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("button.btn-xs:nth-child(1)")).Click();
SelectElement selectCountry = new SelectElement (driver.FindElement(By.Id("country")));
selectCountry.SelectByText ("something");
```

The first info of a test is:

> desiredCapabilities: {"browserName":"internet explorer"}
>   => {"takesScreenshot":true,"unexpectedAlertBehaviour":"dismiss","ie.browserCommandLineSwitches":"","browserAttachTimeout":0,"ie.ensureCleanSession":false,"ignoreProtectedModeSettings":false,"platform":"WINDOWS","version":"11","ignoreZoomSetting":false,"nativeEvents":true,"handlesAlerts":true,"javascriptEnabled":true,"requireWindowFocus":false,"ie.usePerProcessProxy":false,"initialBrowserUrl":`"http://localhost:11130/"`,"enableElementCacheCleanup":true,"cssSelectorsEnabled":true,"browserName":"internet
>   explorer","elementScrollBehavior":0,"enablePersistentHover":true,"ie.forceCreateProcessApi":false}

I do not know what I am doing wrong. Other tests for Firefox and Chrome works correctly. Any ideas what is wrong here?